# How to fetch and render specific data from an API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api

I have an API of flight information, 
each flight has the following info under separate keys:
id,
departure airport, 
arrival airport,
departure time,
arrival time.

This is the question I have been asked:
What’s the average journey time between London Heathrow (LHR) and Dubai (DXB)?

The API has around 7000 flights, some of which are between LHR and DXB.

Using React.js, how would I return specific data from the API like the answer to above question?

I have a fetch request, and can render the full list of flights by id, name, etc

Essentially how do i perform calculations / conditionals, on the api data itself?

Comment: This depends entirely on that API and what sort of functionality it exposes.  We don't know what API you're using, so we can only suggest to read its documentation.

Comment: it's an internal API from a mongoDB database, that I created and populated myself using a csv file @Brad

Comment: @TheoWright is there a specific problem you are are encountering while working on this? Because it sounds like the general steps you need to preform are 1) query flights collection for flights departing from LHR and arriving in DXB, or departing from DXB and arriving in LHR. 2) calulate the flight duration for each of the returned flights (difference between arrival time and departure time). 3) average the flight duration.

Comment: @XionDark this is exactly what i want to do, but i do not know how to go about it.  how would i approach this from within react?  is there a specific term/name for doing this?  do i write this as a function?  or does this need to be done in render() ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some functions to filter the values you are looking for, this is just a dirty example considering that your flights are inside an array of objects:

```
const getFlights = (airporta, airportb) => flights.filter(fly => (
  (fly['departure airport'] === airporta && fly['arrival airport'] === airportb)
  || (fly['departure airport'] === airportb && fly['arrival airport'] === airporta)
));

const lhrdbx = getFlights('LHR', 'DXB');

const difference = lhrdbx.reduce((a, b) => (
  a + (b['arrival time'] - b['departure time'])
), 0);
```